# How to use BASIC authentication native prompt from the browser in a SPA + API app?

Tags: fetch, single-page-application, basic-authentication

I'm using FETCH on a js frontend application

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3333/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers({ Accept: "application/json" }),
      credentials: "same-origin",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        else throw new Error("General error");
      })
      .then((jsonData) => console.log({ jsonData }))
      .catch((err) => console.log({ err }));
```

The response is a 401 Unauthorized with `www-authenticate: Basic realm="Login", charset="UTF-8"`

The problem is that the browser doesn't pop up the native username and password prompt from this fetch. It does only if i type "http://localhost:3333/" on the navigation bar.

How can i use browser's native prompt for username and password to login on my frontend?

Comment: Is your SPA served from localhost:3333 or a different address?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and should pop browser prompt, but only if html page was served from localhost:3333 too, hence `credentials: "same-origin"`

In the case when HTML page and JSON API are served from different hosts, you have to pass CORS validation.

On frontend send credentials with flag `include`

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3333/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers({ Accept: "application/json" }),
      credentials: "include",
    })
```

On API backend respond with headers, allowing CORS requests from HTML page, in this case localhost:8000

```sh
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```